# Having Trouble with Perl if then Statements

Tags: perl, if-statement, statements

I'm having trouble making yes/no questions with Perl, and I just couldn't figure it out. I'm kinda a noob at this.

```
#! usr/bin/perl

print "Hello there!\n";
print "What is your favorite game?\n";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;
print "That's awesome! $name is my favorite game too!\n";

print "Do you think this is a fun script (Y/n) \n";
$status = <STDIN>;
if [ $status = "y" ]: then

print "YAY! I knew you would like it!\n";

if [ $status = "n" ]: then

print "You suck, not me!\n";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perl if statements do not use square brackets to enclose the condition, they use parentheses. They also don't use the `then` keyword. `if ( $status eq 'y' ) { } elsif { } else { }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if [` is a shell syntax. In Perl, you should use

```
if (...) {
```

Also, `=` is the assignment operator. For string equality, use `eq`:

```
if ($status eq 'y') {
    print "YAY\n";
```

Before comparing, you should `chomp` $status the same way you're already chomping $name.

Also, note that `Y` and `y` are not equal.

Also, your first ("shebang") line misses the starting slash:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm a noob.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ $status = "y" ]: then
```

That's Bourne (or bash) shell syntax. The equivalent Perl code is:

```
if ($status eq "y") {
    # ...
}
```

`eq` is equality comparison for strings; `==` compares numbers.

(The other thing you're doing wrong is not including the error message in your question.)

For example:

```
$status = <STDIN>;
chomp $status;
if ($status eq "y") {
    print "YAY! I knew you would like it!\n";
}
```

There are some other things you can do to improve your Perl code. For example, you should always have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

near the top of the source file (which will require declaring your variables, probably with `my`). I suggest getting this program working first before worrying about that, but it's definitely something you'll want to do in the long term.

Comment: Can you give me an example of my code _with_ your solution? I tried fixing it, but it shows both responses instead of just the intended one.

Answer (score 1):

First, always, always put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your programs. This will catch all sorts of errors such as using `=` in `if` statements. `=` sets a variable's value. `==` tests numeric equality and `eq` tests string equality.

Here's your program rewritten. The first line with `#!` searches your PATH for an executable Perl. This way, you don't have to worry whether Perl is in `/usr/bin/perl` or `/bin/perl` or `/usr/local/bin/perl`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env  perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);   # Allows the use of the "say" command

say "Hello there!";
print "What is your favorite game? ";
my $name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;
say "That's awesome! $name is my favorite game too!";

print "Do you think this is a fun script (Y/n) \n";
my $status = <STDIN>;
chomp $status;
if ( $status eq "y" ) {
    say "Yay! I knew you would like it!";
}
elsif ( $status eq "n" ) {
    say "You suck, not me!";
}
```

A better way may be to check whether the input started with a `y` or not:

```
if ( $status =~ /^y/i ) {   # Did it start with a 'y' or 'Y'?
    say "Yay! I knew you would like it!";
else {
    say "You suck, not me!";
}
```

Note the use of `my` to declare variables. This is something `use strict;` requires and will catch a lot of programming mistakes. Note that `say` is like `print`, but I don't have to keep putting `\n` on the end.

Comment: Very helpful! I appreciate all the trouble you've been through. :)

Comment: @ysth -- oops! Corrected.

Comment: @ysth I actually prefer to use `chomp ( my $var = <STDIN> );`. Using this over and over makes the syntax _natural_ for me to use, and I never forget to `chomp` on a read. However, it can be confusing for people, so I tend to use a separate `chomp` here.